# I'm stuck in a task with FOR and IF functions in R data programming

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

So currently i'm stuck in a problem around FOR and IF function.

I have a full working code like this:

```
#my data input
demand.variation=c(1,4,20,23,37)
demand.probability=c(0.81,0.85,0.89,0.93,0.97)
n.month=25

#generating result matrix
result=matrix(0,n.month,2)
colnames(result)=c("Month","Demand")

#filling result matrix with month index and random demand value
result[,1]=1:n.month
random=runif(n.month,0,1)

#return demand value based on random value
for (i in seq_along(random)) {
  if (random[i]>demand.probability[5]) result[i,2]=demand.variation[5]
  else if (random[i]>demand.probability[4]) result[i,2]=demand.variation[4]
  else if (random[i]>demand.probability[3]) result[i,2]=demand.variation[3]
  else if (random[i]>demand.probability[2]) result[i,2]=demand.variation[2]
  else if (random[i]>demand.probability[1]) result[i,2]=demand.variation[1]
  else result[i,2]=0
}

#final result
result
```

It is fully working with the result:

```
> result
      Month Demand
 [1,]     1      0
 [2,]     2      0
 [3,]     3      0
 [4,]     4      0
 [5,]     5      0
 [6,]     6      0
 [7,]     7      0
 [8,]     8      0
 [9,]     9      4
[10,]    10      0
[11,]    11      0
[12,]    12     23
[13,]    13     37
[14,]    14      0
[15,]    15      1
[16,]    16      0
[17,]    17      0
[18,]    18      0
[19,]    19      1
[20,]    20     20
[21,]    21      0
[22,]    22      0
[23,]    23      0
[24,]    24      0
[25,]    25      0
```

The thing is, i have to re-run the same code, but with different length and value of `demand.variation` and `demand.probability`, so i will have problem facing dozens variation for those 2 variables since the FOR and IF is manually entered.

My question is how do you generate a flexible code of FOR and IF statement to cover the job of `#return demand value based on random value` code.

footnote: `demand.variation` and `demand.probability` will always have the same vector length, and is correspondingly connected one to another, which means 1st value in `demand.variation` vector have the probability of the 1st value in `demand.probability` vector, and so on

```
demand.variation=c(1,4,20,23,37)
demand.probability=c(0.81,0.85,0.89,0.93,0.97)
```

I would be very grateful if you can help me on this.

Comment: Did you try the `findInterval` answer from your previous post. That should be generalisable for any length vector. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65536884

Comment: Hi, thankyou for helping me out, tbh i haven't tried your suggestion since the previous answer seems to solve my problem already. I will try it along with other suggestions and findout which one works best. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to categorize continuous values (in `random`) by intervals whose limits are given by `demand.probability` and which should be labeled to values given in `demand.variation`.
This, you can do by the `cut()` function in R.
However, you have to add some additional borders (`-Inf`, `Inf` and e.g. the value `0`).

replace your big `for`-loop expression simply by:

```
result[, 2] <- cut(random, breaks=c(-Inf, demand.probability, Inf), labels=c(0, demand.variation))
```

You can do it as a function (with seed for reproducibility):

```
categorize_months <- function(n_months, breaks, labels, seed=42) {
  set.seed(seed)
  random <- runif(n_months, 0, 1)
  months <- 1:n_months
  demands <- cut(random, breaks=c(-Inf, breaks, Inf), labels=c(0, labels))
  df <- data.frame("Month"=months, "Demand"=demands)
  df
}

categorize_months(25, demand.probability, demand.variation, seed=42)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll check and i'll be back in a minute.

Comment: You are welcome! Be aware - the `random` values change every time, because you didn't put a `seed` for controlling the random number generator in R.

Comment: so for controlling - run your for loop and compare with the `cut()` expression's value.

Comment: Hi, I'm back. So i tried your code and it goes so close to solve my problem. Your code did categorize my demand.probability data, but it didn't return the value from demand.variation, instead it returned a number between 1 to 6, which i believe it is the class interval index. It didn't labeled each of the class with demand.variation data. It's really close

Comment: Please keep me informed if there is anything i can do to automatically labeled each category. For now i can manually link the index with my demand.variation data. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see the rule how you came from `demand.probability` to `demand.variation`.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add anothing `for()` loop counting backward from the number of entries in the demand.variation vector.

```
for(i in seq_along(random)){
  for(j in seq_along(demand.variation):1){
    if(random[i] > demand.probability[j]){
      result[i,2] <-  demand.variation[j]
    } else {
      result[i,2] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Clarification:

So I broke what you want into several functions and combined into a master function that can be called for whatever length/combination required:

```
create.demand.variation <- function(vector){
  return(demand.probability <- c(vector))
}

create.demand.probability <- function(vector){
  return(demand.probability <- c(vector))
}

create.random <- function(n.month){
  return(random <- runif(n.month, 0, 1))
}

create.result <- function(n.month){
  result=matrix(0,n.month,2)
  colnames(result)=c("Month","Demand")
  result[,1]=1:n.month
  return(result)
}

create.random <- function(n.month){
  return(random <- runif(n.month,0,1))
}

get.result <- function(demand.variation, demand.probability, random.vector, result){
  for(i in 1:length(random)){
    k <- length(demand.probability)
    while(k >= 1){
      if(random[i] > demand.probability[k]){
        result[i,2] <- demand.variation[k]
        k <- 0
      } else {
        k <- k - 1
      }
    }
  }
  return(result)
}

master.function <- function(vector.demand, vector.prob, n.month ){
  create.demand.variation(vector.demand) -> demand.variation
  create.demand.probability(vector.prob) -> demand.probability
  create.random(n.month) -> random.vector
  create.result(n.month) -> result
  get.result(demand.variation, demand.probability, random.vector, result) -> result
  return(result)
}
```

So for the example vectors, you would type:

```
master.function(c(1,4,20,23,37), c(0.81, 0.85, 0.89, 0.93, 0.97), 25) -> 
result
```

For me, this produces:

```
> result
      Month Demand
 [1,]     1      0
 [2,]     2     20
 [3,]     3      0
 [4,]     4      0
 [5,]     5      0
 [6,]     6      0
 [7,]     7      1
 [8,]     8      0
 [9,]     9      4
[10,]    10      0
[11,]    11     20
[12,]    12      0
[13,]    13     23
[14,]    14      0
[15,]    15      0
[16,]    16      0
[17,]    17      0
[18,]    18      0
[19,]    19      0
[20,]    20      0
[21,]    21      0
[22,]    22      0
[23,]    23      0
[24,]    24      0
[25,]    25      1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to use your code on my program but it does not seem to work the way i wanted to. Beside, i got 25 warnings telling me that:

(In seq_along(demand.variation):1 :
  numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used.)

I'll be back after doing some research and modification to your code, for now it still does not solve my problem.

Comment: Odd I used it and received a non-error output. I’ll work on it a tad later to see if I can improve it for you.

Comment: So i checked your code and found this:

your code only give 2 possibility of output, the demand.variation[j] and 0. My intention is if the random[i] is not > demand.probability[j], it should check if the random[i] is > demand.probability[j-1] or not, and keep checking until the first value on demand.probability vector. If in the end the random[i] is smaller than the first value in demand.probability vector, then it's ok to return 0.

Do you got the idea?

Comment: See edited solution then. I think I understand now.